# namespace with classes and objects in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
namespace string {

class string {

    string a;

    public: 
        string() {

            string ( const string *q ): a(*q) 

            { }


            string (string &r):a(r.a) 

            { }


            string (const std::string &_a):a(_a) 

            { }        


            ~demo ()  {

            }

            void show () {
               cout << a; 
            }   

            void change (const std::string &_a) {
               a = _a;
            }
        };
    }
}


using namespace string;
    int main () {

        demo s1;
        demo s2("Hello");
        demo s3(s2);                
        s1.show();
        s2.show();
        s3.show();
        s2.change("Java");
        s2.show();
        s3.show();
    }
```

> Desired OUTPUT is Hello Hello Java  Hello

I want To define a namespace i.e. string. And in there is a header file in c++ i.e.. string both have same name

so how can i code the program to avoid nameclash between these two same names in c++.

Comment: Don't name it `string` and don't introduce the entire `std` namespace in the current scope.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read due to the variable amount of indentation and having an empty line everywhere. Please consider formatting it nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your professor wants you to understand following things,

1. Namespaces, what is the purpose of it.
2. Do not pollute your namespace. (`using namespace std;`)
3. Different kind of constructors.

Tried to compile your program. Not sure all your intentions are correct in following successfully compiled solution. Check it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Do not pollute the global namespace with using namespace.
//using namespace std;
namespace string {

class string {

    std::string a; // Assume you need to store a string inside your class.

    public: 
        string() {};

        string (const std::string *q ) : a(*q) { }

        string (string &r):a(r.a) { }

        string (const std::string &_a):a(_a) { }        

        ~string()  {}

        void show () {
            std::cout << a; 
        }

        void change (const std::string &_a) {
        a = _a;
        }
    }; // ~class end
};   //~namespace end


int main () {

    // Use full namespace qualified ID everywhere
    string::string s1;
    string::string s2("Hello");
    string::string s3(s2);                
    s1.show();
    s2.show();
    s3.show();
    s2.change("Java");
    s2.show();
    s3.show();
}
```

Do not use this straightaway. Learn following things.

1. [Namespace pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1) - `using namespace std` in headers are bad.
2. [Purpose of namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Comment: Output : https://onlinegdb.com/ry1tcm-dQ

Comment: thanks you very much PraAnj ...

Comment: Don't take only the compiled program. Learn the concepts well.

Comment: I am Wisely understanding these concepts....

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid using names that are too generic like `string` for your classes, functions and variables.
2. Avoid `using namespace std` when you include the headers. Instead use the specific functions of that namespace (e.g. `cout`) like this `std::cout` wherever required.

Comment: I know using string throws error .... but I have to do it this way for assignment..that's why i was asking it.

Comment: Should your namespace name also be string?

Comment: yes my namespace name also is string.

Comment: Then whenever you want to use your own string class, you should use `string::string`. When you want to use the C++ library class, you should use `std::string`. See an example here: http://cpp.sh/442e7

Comment: but in my program i am not receiving any arguements from user...

Comment: That's just an example to show the use of string from two different namespaces. You can adapt it as per your requirement.